# Redirect trafic to host toward an internal VM with nftables does not works

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, nat

My issue is the following :
On an ubuntu 20 host . i got some multipass hypervisor and VMs, that i want to be able to reach from the outside.

- physical host :  eth1 192.168.10.33/16
- vm : mpqemubr0 10.54.32.232/24

The forwarding is enabled:

```
cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep forward
# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

It's also enabled on each interface :

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/mpqemubr0/forwarding
1

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding 
1
```

iptables and ufw are disabled, and nftables is installed.

the nftables config is the following :

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
flush ruleset
table ip nat {
        chain prerouting {
            type nat hook prerouting priority 100;
            
            ip daddr 192.168.10.33 tcp dport {80,8080} dnat 10.54.32.232:8080
        }
        chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
            ip saddr 10.54.32.0/24 oifname {eth0,mpqemubr0} masquerade
        }
}
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0;
            ip daddr 10.54.32.232 accept
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0;
    }
}
```

- from the host i can telnet the vm on port 8080
- from the outside i can reach the host
- from the vm i can ping the outside

i can NOT redirect the trafic from outside to host toward vm and with tcpdump (from the host) the system see the packet arrive but then nothing goes out on port 8080 or for host 10.54.32.232:

```
sudo tcpdump -i any -n port 80 or port 8080 -vvvv
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
14:30:36.229571 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 5375, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.55.55.16.38848 > 192.168.10.33.80: Flags [S], cksum 0x71ba (correct), seq 560636356, win 64860, options [mss 1380,sackOK,TS val 1972236760 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Obviously the VM see nothing entering its interface

It used to works with another vm on the same host  but i had to recreate it, the new vm took another IP, and even after changing the nftables.conf to match the new vm ip, it doesn't work anymore (BTW the old one doesn't exist anymore).

I think i missed a configuration but where ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: The outside means another computer on the same LAN as host?

Comment: it's another computer but in another lan than host. VM can reach both this computer and internet

Comment: For debug: change your tcpdump so you capture also ARP and ICMP, not just TCP. You should always think about this. Then add -e for Ethernet (to distinguish which side).

Comment: nftables doesn't look wrong (and does not firewall anything). You should give your network configuration (don't omit other interfaces if any other): `ip -br link; ip -br -4 address; ip -4 route; ip -4 neigh; ip -4 rule; bridge link`. Also be sure there's no iptables legacy in use: `iptables-legacy-save` (which should be quite empty).